# How to convert a ruby hash object to JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, hashmap

How to convert a ruby hash object to JSON? So I am trying this example below & it doesn't work?

I was looking at the RubyDoc and obviously `Hash` object doesn't have a `to_json` method. But I am reading on blogs that Rails supports `active_record.to_json` and also supports `hash#to_json`. I can understand `ActiveRecord` is a Rails object, but `Hash` is not native to Rails, it's a pure Ruby object. So in Rails you can do a `hash.to_json`, but not in pure Ruby??

```
car = {:make => "bmw", :year => "2003"}
car.to_json
```

Comment: beware though, if the object on which you call `to_json` is already json, you'll get a mess: `{ foo: "bar" }.to_json.to_json`

Answer (score 644, accepted):

One of the numerous niceties of Ruby is the possibility to extend existing classes with your own methods. That's called "class reopening" or monkey-patching (the meaning of the latter [can vary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394144/what-does-monkey-patching-exactly-mean-in-ruby), though).

So, take a look here:

```
car = {:make => "bmw", :year => "2003"}
# => {:make=>"bmw", :year=>"2003"}
car.to_json
# NoMethodError: undefined method `to_json' for {:make=>"bmw", :year=>"2003"}:Hash
#   from (irb):11
#   from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
require 'json'
# => true
car.to_json
# => "{"make":"bmw","year":"2003"}"
```

As you can see, requiring `json` has magically brought method `to_json` to our `Hash`.

Comment: all i can say is wow :) also thanks  a lot!!

so basically i was able to extend the json class dynamically??

Comment: I tried the same thing with Ruby object and it does not work??


>> require 'json'
=> true
>> class Person
>> attr_accessor :fname, :lname
>> end
=> nil
>> p = Person.new
=> #<Person:0x101155f70>
>> p.fname = "Bill"
=> "Bill"
>> p.lname = "Shine"
=> "Shine"
>> p.to_json
=> "\"#<Person:0x101155f70>\""

Comment: No, no, someone has to code how the object of an arbitrary class should be serialized to JSON. They did it for `Hash` and `Array` classes in `json` gem, but your class `Person` is just a plain `Object`. But you can inherit `Hash` instead. You can open a new question if you don't manage.

Comment: thanks. here's the new question, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226054/how-to-convert-a-ruby-object-to-json

Comment: You're showing what looks to be IRB type output. I was trying to get hash#to_json to work for DateTime object. Thanks to this post I got it. But I did inspect with p date_json  This is what I got for a true string "{\"year\":2013,\"mon\":7,\"mday\":16,\"hour\":13,\"min\":54,\"sec\":32,\"zone\":\"-05:00\",\"offset\":-18000}" so you may see that it is making the key symbols as strings and of course that data is unchanged. Thanks again. Sorry I'm so late though.

Comment: Is the `json` gem built-in to Ruby installations, or do you need to grab it with `gem install json`?

Comment: Hmm, when I do this in IRB now I get different results. All the double quote characters are escaped: `"{\"make\":\"bmw\",\"year\":\"2003\"}"`

Answer (score 22):

```
require 'json/ext' # to use the C based extension instead of json/pure

puts {hash: 123}.to_json
```

Answer (score 19):

You can also use `JSON.generate`:

```
require 'json'

JSON.generate({ foo: "bar" })
=> "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
```

Or its alias, `JSON.unparse`:

```
require 'json'

JSON.unparse({ foo: "bar" })
=> "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
```

Comment: JSON.generate only allows objects or arrays to be converted to JSON syntax. to_json, however, accepts many Ruby classes even though it acts only as a method for serialization: 1.to_json # => "1".   Docs here: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html

Answer (score 17):

Add the following line on the top of your file

```
require 'json'
```

Then you can use:

```
car = {:make => "bmw", :year => "2003"}
car.to_json
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
JSON.generate({:make => "bmw", :year => "2003"})
```