# How to convert a Ruby object to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I would like to do something like this:

```
require 'json'

class Person
attr_accessor :fname, :lname
end

p = Person.new
p.fname = "Mike"
p.lname = "Smith"

p.to_json
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 48):

Yes, you can do it with [`to_json`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Generating+JSON).

You may need to `require 'json'` if you're not running Rails.

Comment: With Rails it's not necessary to use `require 'json'`, but with regular Ruby code it's likely to be necessary. [JSON is part of Ruby's Standard Library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/json/rdoc/index.html) so it comes with the language.

Answer (score 38):

To make your Ruby class JSON-friendly without touching Rails, you'd define two methods:

- `to_json`, which returns a JSON object
- `as_json`, which returns a hash representation of the object

When your object responds properly to both `to_json` and `as_json`, it can behave properly even when it is nested deep inside other standard classes like Array and/or Hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'json'

class Person

    attr_accessor :fname, :lname

    def as_json(options={})
        {
            fname: @fname,
            lname: @lname
        }
    end

    def to_json(*options)
        as_json(*options).to_json(*options)
    end

end

p = Person.new
p.fname = "Mike"
p.lname = "Smith"

# case 1
puts p.to_json                  # output: {"fname":"Mike","lname":"Smith"}

# case 2
puts [p].to_json                # output: [{"fname":"Mike","lname":"Smith"}]

# case 3
h = {:some_key => p}
puts h.to_json                  # output: {"some_key":{"fname":"Mike","lname":"Smith"}}

puts JSON.pretty_generate(h)    # output
                                # {
                                #   "some_key": {
                                #     "fname": "Mike",
                                #     "lname": "Smith"
                                #   }
                                # }
```

Also see "[Using custom to_json method in nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879589/using-custom-to-json-method-in-nested-objects/6880638#6880638)".

Answer (score 22):

Try it. If you're using Ruby on Rails (and the tags say you are), I think this exact code should work already, without requiring anything.

Rails supports JSON output from controllers, so it already pulls in all of the JSON serialization code that you will ever need. If you're planning to output this data through a controller, you might be able to save time by just writing

```
render :json => @person
```

Comment: What is Person has associations?

Comment: This answer only applies to Rails projects. What about vanilla Ruby?

Comment: I'd say it doesn't even apply to Rails.. it only apply to the controller inside a rails app.. very limited scope.