# Serialize and Deserialize object over rabbitmq in ruby

Tags: ruby, json, rabbitmq, amqp

I want to serialise an object into JSON send it across the wire via rabbitmq and then deserialize it.

I have the following object that I am serialising:

```
lead = Lead.new

lead.company = 'some company'

operation = proc{ AMQP::Exchange.default.publish(
                                lead.to_json, 
                                :routing_key => header.reply_to,
                                :correlation_id => header.correlation_id
                              )}
```

On the other side, I am trying to descerialise the object like this:

```
callback_queue.subscribe do |header, body|
  puts "received #{body.inspect}"

  lead = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode body

  puts lead.company #NoMethodError: undefined method `company' for #<Array:0x6fe03f3b>
```

The json is strangely an array of 3 hashes and looks like this.

```
[{\"created_at\":null,\"email\":\"dagda1@scotalt.net\",\"id\":null,\"lead_id\":null,\"updated_at\":null},{\"created_at\":null,\"email\":\"paul.cowan@continuity2.com\",\"id\":null,\"lead_id\":null,\"updated_at\":null}]"
```

Can anyone see anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464050/ruby-objects-and-json-serialization-without-rails

Comment: my problem is that I cannot decode the object.  I don't understand why the object does not decode properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same aproach more or less, and works correctly in my side. Probably you are sending a incorrect message (serialization problem). With new rabbitmq you can inspect the message in the rabbit web console.

You could try to print to_json before.

Comment: thank you for the heads up.  It is reassuring to know it should work and the problem is at my end.