# how to access from javascript, my_ruby_obj.price sent to browser as my_ruby_obj.to_json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, json

**In ruby:**

```
class Obj
  attr_accessor :price
end

my_ruby_obj = Obj.new
```

puts my_ruby_obj.to_json

```
"\"#<Obj:0x1c9b018>\""
```

**Server sends my_ruby_obj.to_json to browser** (sinatra, with content_type :json) in response to a jquery ajax request (with $.get), which correctly defines a return type of json, and launches a callback function(data) which does:

`console.log(data);`

which returns:

```
#<Obj:0x1c9b018>
```

**Now how do I access "data.price" attribute in javascript/jquery** as I would normally do on a ruby object to access its attribute? ("my_ruby_obj.price")

I tried with console.log(data.price);

```
> Undefined
```

I feel I am missing a big piece here.. and I guess it has to do with how json works with objects..

Any help ?
*If possible*, I'm looking for a correct way to do it with jquery.

Thanks

**edit:** 
trying to understand what is going on, I tried this in the callback:

```
newdata = $.parseJSON(data);
```

but debug console halts on it showing:

```
> uncaught exception: Invalid JSON: #<Obj:0x1c9b018>
```

I did call .to_json on the ruby object, so why it says so? ...

[[**new_edit:**]]

Seems like ruby json serialization for objects from custom classes is not working as I supposed:

Quoting from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4464721/988591

> It will be a bit more difficult for objects from your own classes. For
>   the following class, to_json will produce something like
>   `"\"#<A:0xb76e5728>\""`. This probably isn't desirable. To effectively
>   serialise your object as JSON, you should create your own to_json
>   method.

and examples are following... 
But.. wow... isn't there an easier way ?

Comment: downvoters, care to confront your opinion here on why you are downvoting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ok I found exactly what I was looking for**! An automated quick solution, which also comes with other side benefits (more speed!).

The standard json gem only works for some classes (Array, Hash,..) and can't translate a custom class/object you have created to JSON. It doesn't know how to organize data, unless you write yourself a custom .to_json method for your class, which is what I was tring to avoid..

So in the end I found a gem called **Oj**: [Optimized Json](https://github.com/ohler55/oj) (gem install oj)

Quoting the authors:

> Optimized JSON (Oj), as the name implies was written to provide speed
> optimized JSON handling. It was designed as a faster alternative to
> Yajl and other the common Ruby JSON parsers. So far is has achieved
> that at about **2 time faster than Yajl for parsing and 3 or more times
> faster writing JSON**.
>
> **Oj has several dump or serialization modes which control how Objects are converted to JSON.** These modes are set with the :mode option in
> either the default options or as one of the options to the dump()
> method.
>
> ***:object* mode will dump any Object as a JSON Object with keys that
> match the Ruby Object's variable names without the '@' character**. This
> is the highest performance mode.

I used it like so:

**`json = Oj.dump(guy, mode: :object)`** but in my case it worked without mode: :object as well.

now `console.log(data);` shows:

```
({'^o':"Human", x:38, y:58, name:"Jack", bday:{'^t':1352083824.5625}, age:50})
```

**Now that the serialization is working good, I can finally do:**

**`console.log(data.age);` // ---> 50**

Serialization is faster too.

..It has been a long ride though ;)

A big Thank You goes to the library author: http://twitter.com/#!/peterohler

Comment: By the way, now I asking myself if a more "standard" way to deal with this is splitting the object in small bits and then serialize them, and send them piece by piece ? Like @Michael Shimmins said: my_ruby_obj.price.to_json , then my_ruby_obj.color.to_json, then..., and soo on ? Ok.. enough.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the string representation of your object via javascript, not the object its self.

You need to return a JSON representation fo it:

```
render json: my_ruby_obj.to_json
```

Or even better, if you know the fields you need to access:

```
render json: {price: my_ruby_obj.price}
```

Comment: are you sure this applies to Sinatra and not to Rails? Please look at the following example http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-return-json-from-sinatra

Comment: The same theory will apply in regards to what you're sending over the wire from the server to the client via JSON. Not sure if `to_json` is available in a sinatra app. You're just sending a simple string "#<Obj:0x1c9b018>" - need to send actual json.

Comment: you were right, but it leads to an "ugly" solution. :\ check new_edit to the question please.