# JSON Object into Ruby (Rails) Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, session, object

Is there a way to convert JSON objects into Rails? What I'm trying to do is converting many Rails (Active Record) Objects into JSON, so I can take them into the session cookies and use them when the user needs the information. If you've got any better idea don't mind to say it.

Comment: This should interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464050/ruby-objects-and-json-serialization-without-rails

Comment: You do know that cookies are limited to 4kb, right? And that storing sensitive information in a cookie is undesirable?

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a [to_json](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveResource/Base/to_json) method which you can use.

e.g

```
User.first.to_json
```

will return

```
"{\"id\":1,\"username\":\"test_user\"}
```