# When to use dump vs. generate vs. to_json and load vs. parse in Ruby's JSON lib?

Tags: ruby, json

david4dev's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464050/ruby-objects-and-json-serialization-without-rails) claims that there are three equivalent ways to convert an object to a JSON string using the `json` library:

```
JSON.dump(object)
JSON.generate(object)
object.to_json
```

and two equivalent ways to convert a JSON string to an object:

```
JSON.load(string)
JSON.parse(string)
```

But looking at the source code, each of them seems to be pretty much different, and there are some differences between them (e.g., [1](https://github.com/flori/json/pull/145)).

What are the differences among them? When to use which?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

In general:

- Use `to_json` (or the equivalent `JSON::generate`).
- Use `JSON::parse`.

For some special use cases, you may want `dump` or `load`, but it's unsafe to use `load` on data you didn't create yourself.

---

**Extended Explanation:**

`JSON::dump` **vs** `JSON::generate`

As part of its argument signature, `JSON::generate` allows you to set options such as indent levels and whitespace particulars. `JSON::dump`, on the other hand, calls `::generate` within itself, with specific pre-set options, so you lose the ability to set those yourself.

According to the docs, `JSON::dump` is meant to be part of the `Marshal::dump` implementation scheme. The main reason you'd want to explicitly use `::dump` yourself would be that you are about to stream your JSON data (over a socket for instance), since `::dump` allows you to pass an IO-like object as the second argument. Unfortunately, the JSON data being produced is not really streamed *as* it is produced; it is created en masse and only sent once the JSON is fully created. This makes having an IO argument useful only in trivial cases.

The final difference between the two is that `::dump` can also take a `limit` argument that causes it to raise an ArgumentError when a certain nesting depth is exceeded.

---

**Comparison to** `#to_json`

`#to_json` accepts options as arguments, so internal implementation aside, `JSON::generate(foo, opts)` and `foo.to_json(opts)` are equivalent.

---

`JSON::load` **vs** `JSON::parse`

Similar to `::dump` calling `::generate` internally, `::load` calls `::parse` internally. `::load`, like `::dump`, may also take an IO object, but again, the source is read all at once, so streaming is limited to trivial cases. However, unlike the `::dump`/`::generate` duality, both `::load` and `::parse` accept options as part of their argument signatures.

`::load` can also be passed a proc, which will be called on every Ruby object parsed from the data; it also comes with a warning that `::load` should only be used with trusted data. `::parse` has no such restriction, and therefore `JSON::parse` is the correct choice for parsing untrusted data sources like user inputs and files or streams with unknown contents.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Very well explained.