# Ruby object to json

Tags: ruby, json

I am trying to create an object and convert it to json.

```
require 'json'

class Person
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name
  def to_json
    hash = {}
    self.instance_variables.each do |var|
      hash[var] = self.instance_variable_get var
    end
    hash.to_json
  end
end

person = Person.new
person.first_name = "Michael"
person.last_name = "Jordon"
```

I get the output:

```
person.to_json
# => {"@first_name":"Michael","@last_name":"Jordon"}
```

What's the change I have to make so that the `@` symbol does not come as part of variable names in json string?

Comment: If you're going to do it manually, then use normal string manipulation to remove leading `@` from the symbols (which are symbols; that's a hint you'd want to convert it to a string). There are a ton of libraries that'll do all this for you, though.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the line:

```
hash[var] = self.instance_variable_get var
```

to:

```
hash[var.to_s[1..-1]] = self.instance_variable_get var
```

You'll get:

```
puts person.to_json
  #=> {"first_name":"Michael","last_name":"Jordon"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rails Active Support JSON extension

```
require 'active_support/json'

class Person
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name
end

person = Person.new
person.first_name = "Michael"
person.last_name = "Jordon"

puts ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(person)
# {"first_name":"Michael","last_name":"Jordon"}
```

More options explained here - [Ruby objects and JSON serialization (without Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464050/ruby-objects-and-json-serialization-without-rails)

Comment: I do not want to use additional libraries. Preferably would like to do with ruby +json libs Thanks !

Comment: Okay, that may not be trivial task - even default Ruby implementation of `JSON#generate` (conveniently) deals with hash-like objects.  But, it will be fun - so, have fun!