# Custom to_json for nested complex objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I'm new to `Ruby` and having a little trouble `json`. I have inherited my classes with custom made `JSONable` class, as explained [HERE in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464050/ruby-objects-and-json-serialization-without-rails#answer-4464721). I have customized it according to my need, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work with custom nested (complex) objects, according to my requirement. I have following scenario.

First Class:

```
 class Option < JSONable

 def IncludeAll=(includeAll) #bool
  @includeAll = includeAll
 end

 def IncludeAddress=(includeAddress) #bool
  @includeAddress= includeAddress
 end

 ......
```

Second Class:

```
class Search < JSONable

def CustomerId=(customerId)
  @customerId = customerId
end

def identifier=(identifier)
  @identifier = identifier
end

def Options=(options) #This is expected to be of Class Option, declared above
 @options = options
end
```

Third Class:

```
class Request < JSONable

def DateTimeStamp=(dateTimeStamp)
 @dateTimeStamp = dateTimeStamp
end

def SDKVersion=(sDKVersion)
 @sDKVersion = sDKVersion
end

def RequestMessage=(requestMessage) #This is of type Search, declared above
 @requestMessage = requestMessage
end
```

I call it as:

```
search = Search.new
searchOpts = Options.new
request = Request.new

search.identifier = identifier

searchOpts.IncludeAll = false
searchOpts.IncludeAddress = true

search.Options = searchOpts #setting nested level2 property here

//THE MOST OUTER CLASS OBJECT
request.SDKVersion = "xyz"
request.RequestMessage = search #setting nested level1
```

My ultimate goal is to send this `request` object to an `API`, after converting it to JSON. so i call `to_json` on `request` object as:

```
request.to_json
```

But here, suggested solution in that post *(JSONable)* fails in this case, as it can't convert the nested complex objects `request.search` and `request.search.Options` to Json.

*(gives error: in 'to_json': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)')*

What I tried:

```
class JSONable
def to_json
    hash = {}
    self.instance_variables.each do |var|
     #hash[var] = self.instance_variable_get var #tried to apply following check

    if((self.instance_variable_get var).instance_of? Options ||((varVal).instance_of? Search))
     varVal = self.instance_variable_get var
     hash[var] = varVal.to_json #convert inner object to json
    else 
     hash[var] = self.instance_variable_get var
    end

    end
    hash.to_json
end
.....
```

This converts the nested model without any problem, but it messes up the 3rd level json. The result is as following:

```
{"DateTimeStamp":"121212","SDKVersion":"1.5","Culture":"en","RequestMessage":"{\"identifier\":\"851848913\",\"Options\":\"{\\\"IncludeAll\\\":true,\\\"IncludeAssociatedEntities\\\":true,\\\"IncludeAddress\\\":true,\\\"IncludePaymentInstructions\\\":true}\"}"}
```

And API doesn't respond. It seems as it messes up the boolean variables, which should be something like:

`"SearchOption":"{\"IncludeAll\":true,\"IncludeAssociatedEntities\":true,\...`

but it gives:

`"SearchOption\":\"{\\\"IncludeAll\\\":true,\\\"IncludeAssociatedEntities\\\":true,\\\"Includ...`

So the API logic can't cast it to corresponding `bool` objects anymore. JSON validator also fails to validate this result, i checked online

**Questions:**

- How can I avoid this, and produce valid JSON in this case?
- How can I apply generic check to in my JSONable class to check if the object is of some custom class / complex object.

*(currently i have checked only for specific classes as:)*

`if((self.instance_variable_get var).instance_of? Options ||((varVal).instance_of? Search))`

*Other Info:*

- It works fine for all complex objects, having no nested objects
- API is developed in .NET
- I'm not using Rails, its a Ruby console app (I'm new to Ruby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you referred is dated “Dec 2010.” `JSON` library is included in ruby stdlib for years already and it perfectly converts `Hash` instances to json. That said, you just need to construct hashes out of your objects and then call `JSON.dump` on the resulting hash. I have no idea what `JSONable` is and you definitely do not need it. Introduce some base class, let’s call it `Base`:

```
class Base
  def to_h
    instance_variables.map do |iv|
      value = instance_variable_get(:"@#{iv}")
      [
        iv.to_s[1..-1], # name without leading `@`
        case value
        when Base then value.to_h # Base instance? convert deeply
        when Array # Array? convert elements
          value.map do |e|
            e.respond_to?(:to_h) ? e.to_h : e
          end
        else value # seems to be non-convertable, put as is
        end
      ]
    end.to_h
  end
end
```

Now just derive your classes from `Base` to make them respond to `to_h`, define all your instance variables as you did, and call:

```
require 'json'
JSON.dump request.to_h # request.to_h.to_json should work as well
```

The above should produce the nested JSON, hashes are happily converted to json by this library automagically.

Comment: Thank you Mudasobwa. I have a class named `Customer`, it inherits `JSONable`. I placed this `to_h` method in JSONable class, in order to test your suggestion i.e, my JSONable is equivalnt to your Base class. *(replaced `when Base` with `when JSONable`)*. When I call `to_h` on customer object as `result = JSON.dump cutomerObj.to_h`, i get:
*`to_h': undefined local variable or method `instance' for #<Customer:0x00000002dacb20> (NameError)*. What am I missing?

Comment: Or, sorry, `instance` is a rudiment of me testing this. Just remove it; I have updated an answer accordingly.

Comment: additional Info: I have restriction of using no higher version of Ruby, than 2.1.8/2.1.9.

Comment: Ty. can you also confirm the line `end.to_h`? I removed this .to_h and took placed at the end of line above it. i.e ` ].to_h`

Comment: The whole map is to be converted to hash, hence yes, I confirm my code is correct, it should be `map do ... end.to_h`.

Comment: Perfect! .. It worked great. I just had to put `do` in second line. May be due to version difference. Changed second line as:
`instance_variables.map do |iv|`  Gracias ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117767/discussion-between-zeeshan-and-mudasobwa).

Comment: For reference, JSONable is [here](https://github.com/treeder/jsonable). It makes it easier to do this, without having to manually implement a `to_h` method for your class etc.