# How to rename JSON key

Tags: json

I have a JSON object with the following content:

```
[
  {
    "_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb",
    "email":"user1@gmail.com",
    "image":"some_image_url",
    "name":"Name 1"
  },
  {
    "_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfc",
    "email":"user2@gmail.com",
    "image":"some_image_url",
    "name":"Name 2"
  }
]
```

I want to change the "_id" key to "id" so it would become

```
[
  {
    "id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb",
    "email":"user1@gmail.com",
    "image":"some_image_url",
    "name":"Name 1"
  },
  {
    "id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfc",
    "email":"user2@gmail.com",
    "image":"some_image_url",
    "name":"Name 2"
  }
]
```

How would I do that either with Javascript, jQuery or Ruby, Rails?

Thanks.

Comment: Parse the JSON, modify the resulting data structure accordingly and convert it back to JSON. Pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-javascript-array-to-json, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183786/how-to-convert-a-ruby-hash-object-to-json.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

1. Parse the JSON

```
const arr = JSON.parse(json);
```

2. For each object in the JSON, rename the key:

```
obj.id = obj._id;
delete obj._id;
```

3. Stringify the result

All together:

```js
function renameKey ( obj, oldKey, newKey ) {
  obj[newKey] = obj[oldKey];
  delete obj[oldKey];
}

const json = `
  [
    {
      "_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb",
      "email":"user1@gmail.com",
      "image":"some_image_url",
      "name":"Name 1"
    },
    {
      "_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfc",
      "email":"user2@gmail.com",
      "image":"some_image_url",
      "name":"Name 2"
    }
  ]
`;
   
const arr = JSON.parse(json);
arr.forEach( obj => renameKey( obj, '_id', 'id' ) );
const updatedJson = JSON.stringify( arr );

console.log( updatedJson );
```

Comment: what if I want to apply change to all _id in json?

Comment: @truongnm loop it

Comment: also if you want to have keys with spaces you can add it like this obj["my id"] = obj.id

Comment: **Please See Updated Answer Below (2021)** the answer from @md-shayon  seems to me the simplest and [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68816259/8086910)

Comment: Unfortunately the key order is not preserved. The answer by evanmcdonnal does so by stringifying, replacing the key (including the colon to avoid changing values), and parsing back into an object.

Answer (score 31):

In this case it would be easiest to use string replace. Serializing the JSON won't work well because _id will become the property name of the object and changing a property name is no simple task (at least not in most langauges, it's not so bad in javascript). Instead just do;

```
jsonString = jsonString.replace("\"_id\":", "\"id\":");
```

Comment: And what if he will have parameters
`"whereToFindIdentification":"id"` ? its never the best way.

Comment: @Kamil the inclusion of the colon to the right in the regex, won't match your example. It implies a field named id, not a value.

Answer (score 26):

As mentioned by [evanmcdonnal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/763585/evanmcdonnal), the easiest solution is to process this as string instead of JSON,

```js
var json = [{"_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb","email":"user1@gmail.com","image":"some_image_url","name":"Name 1"},{"_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfc","email":"user2@gmail.com","image":"some_image_url","name":"Name 2"}];
    
json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json).split('"_id":').join('"id":'));

document.write(JSON.stringify(json));
```

This will convert given JSON data to string and replace "_id" to "id"  then converting it back to the required JSON format. But I used `split` and `join` instead of `replace`, because `replace` will replace only the first occurrence of the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Stranger, It really help me.

Comment: Clean, short and  well explained. Great!

Answer (score 24):

`JSON.parse` has two parameters. The second parameter, reviver, is a transform function that can format the output format we want. See ECMA specification [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-json.parse).

In reviver function:

- if we return undefined, the original property will be deleted.
- `this` is the object containing the property being processed as this function, and the property name as a string, the property value as arguments of this function.

```
const json = '[{"_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb","email":"user1@gmail.com","image":"some_image_url","name":"Name 1"},{"_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfc","email":"user2@gmail.com","image":"some_image_url","name":"Name 2"}]';

const obj = JSON.parse(json, function(k, v) {
    if (k === "_id") {
        this.id = v;
        return; // if return  undefined, orignal property will be removed
    }
    return v;
});

const res = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(res)
```

output:

```
[{"email":"user1@gmail.com","image":"some_image_url","name":"Name 1","id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb"},{"email":"user2@gmail.com","image":"some_image_url","name":"Name 2","id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfc"}]
```

Comment: This seems like the most correct and clean answer to me. It deals with the problem right at the parsing stage, not ex post like all the others. It also seems like the fastest one, though some benchmarks might be necessary.

Comment: only drawback i see is that the arrangement of elements will be changed. Like in this case, the id is placed at the end of the JSON. If that´s not important for you, then this is a great solution

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
let jsonArr = [
    {
        "_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb",
        "email":"user1@gmail.com",
        "image":"some_image_url",
        "name":"Name 1"
    },
    {
        "_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfc",
        "email":"user2@gmail.com",
        "image":"some_image_url",
        "name":"Name 2"
    }
]

let idModified = jsonArr.map(
    obj => {
        return {
            "id" : obj._id,
            "email":obj.email,
            "image":obj.image,
            "name":obj.name
        }
    }
);
console.log(idModified);
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to rename **all occurrences** of some key you can use a regex with the g option. For example:

```
var json = [{"_id":"1","email":"user1@gmail.com","image":"some_image_url","name":"Name 1"},{"_id":"2","email":"user2@gmail.com","image":"some_image_url","name":"Name 2"}];

str = JSON.stringify(json);
```

now we have the json in string format in str.

Replace all occurrences of "_id" to "id" using regex with the **g** option:

```
str = str.replace(/\"_id\":/g, "\"id\":");
```

and return to json format:

```
json = JSON.parse(str);
```

now we have our json with the wanted key name.

Comment: This won't work if there is a value anywhere containing the key name you are replacing, as it will replace that as well.

Comment: Good point but edge case. Always need to be carefull when replacing text

Answer (score 4):

Is possible, using typeScript

```
function renameJson(json,oldkey,newkey) {    
 return Object.keys(json).reduce((s,item) => 
      item == oldkey ? ({...s,[newkey]:json[oldkey]}) : ({...s,[item]:json[item]}),{})   
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/lelogualda/pen/BeNwWJ

Comment: this is elegant and also saves memory.

Answer (score 3):

By using map function you can do that. 
Please refer below code.

```
var userDetails = [{
  "_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb",
  "email":"user1@gmail.com",
  "image":"some_image_url",
  "name":"Name 1"
},{
  "_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfc",
  "email":"user2@gmail.com",
  "image":"some_image_url",
  "name":"Name 2"
}];

var formattedUserDetails = userDetails.map(({ _id:id, email, image, name }) => ({
  id,
  email,
  image,
  name
}));
console.log(formattedUserDetails);
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone needs to do this dynamically:

```
const keys = Object.keys(jsonObject);

keys.forEach((key) => {

      // CREATE A NEW KEY HERE
      var newKey = key.replace(' ', '_');

      jsonObject[newKey] = jsonObject[key];
      delete jsonObject[key];
   });
```

`jsonObject` will now have the new keys.

IMPORTANT:

If your key is not changed by the `replace` function, it will just take it out of the array. You may want to put some `if` statements in there.

Answer (score 2):

If your object looks like this:

```
obj = {
    "_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb",
    "email":"user1@gmail.com",
    "image":"some_image_url",
    "name":"Name 1"
   }
```

Probably the simplest method in JavaScript is:

```
obj.id = obj._id
del object['_id']
```

As a result, you will get:

```
obj = {
    "id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb",
    "email":"user1@gmail.com",
    "image":"some_image_url",
    "name":"Name 1"
   }
```

Comment: should be `obj.id = obj._id
delete obj['_id']`

Answer (score 1):

If you want replace the key of JSON object, use below logic

```js
const student= {
  "key": "b9ed-9c1a04247482",
  "name": "Devaraju",
  "DOB" : "01/02/2000",
  "score" : "A+"
}
let {key, ...new_student} = {...student}
new_student.id= key

console.log(new_student)
```

Answer (score 0):

To update oldKey with a newKey in a nested json at any deeper level.

```
function transformKeys(object, newKey, oldKey) {
    if(Array.isArray(object)){
        object.map((item) => {
            transformKeys(item, newKey, oldKey)
        })
    }
    if(typeof object === 'object' && !Array.isArray(object)){
        Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
            if (typeof object[key] === 'object') {
                transformKeys(object[key], newKey, oldKey)
            }
            if (key === oldKey) {
                object[newKey] = object[key]
                delete object[key]
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer works for nested json like this,

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "1111111111",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "2222",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "1",
  },
]
```

I want replace key 'id' to 'value', and 'name' to 'label' for select componet.

Function:

```
function renameKeyInJson(json, keys) {
  let dataStr = JSON.stringify(json);
  keys.forEach(e => {
    dataStr = dataStr.replace(new RegExp(`"${e.oldKey}":`, "g"), `"${e.newKey}":`);
  });
  return JSON.parse(dataStr);
}
```

Usage:

```
const response = await getAll(bookId);
return renameKeyInJson(response.data, [
  {oldKey: 'name', newKey: 'label'},
  {oldKey: 'id', newKey: 'value'},
]);
```

Comment: In general it's a bad idea to operate on data by converting to JSON and then doing string operations, when you can just use array and object operations directly. This won't work if any of the properties are not serializable.

Answer (score 0):

My case:

```
renameJsonKey(json, oldKey, newKey) {
    Map<String, dynamic> newJson = {};
    json.forEach((key, value) {
      if (key == oldKey) {
        newJson.addAll({newKey: json[key]});
      } else {
        newJson.addAll({key: json[key]});
      }
    });
    return newJson;
  }
```

Change many keys:

```
renameJsonKeys(json, List<String> oldKeys, List<String> newKeys) {
  Map<String, dynamic> newJson = json;
  for (var i = 0; i < oldKeys.length; i++) {
    newJson = renameJsonKey(newJson, oldKeys[i], newKeys[i]);
  }
  return newJson;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it dynamically, for example, you have an array which you want to apply as a key to JSON object:

your Array will be like :

```
var keys = ["id", "name","Address","Phone"] // The array size should be same as JSON Object keys size
```

Now you have a JSON Array like:

```
var jArray = [
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "_name": "Asna",
    "Address": "NY",
    "Phone": 123
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "_name": "Euphoria",
    "Address": "Monaco",
    "Phone": 124
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "_name": "Ahmed",
    "Address": "Mumbai",
    "Phone": 125
  }
]

$.each(jArray ,function(pos,obj){
    var counter = 0;
    $.each(obj,function(key,value){
        jArray [pos][keys[counter]] = value;
        delete jArray [pos][key];
        counter++;
    })  
})
```

Your resultant JSON Array will be like :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Asna",
    "Address": "NY",
    "Phone": 123
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Euphoria",
    "Address": "Monaco",
    "Phone": 124
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Ahmed",
    "Address": "Mumbai",
    "Phone": 125
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

For a more flexible solution for renaming a key in an object,

Usage:

```
jsondata = renameKey(jsondata,"_id","id");
```

Function:

```
function renameKey(data,oldname,newname)
{
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let element = data[i];
        element[newname] = element[oldname];
        delete element[oldname];
    }
    return data;
}
```

if you need the keys to stay in the same order (like i did) here is a messy solution that I'm sure is poorly optimized.

```
function renameKey(data,oldname,newname)
{
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        let element = data[i];
        let info = Object.keys(data[i]);

        for (let ii = 0; ii < info.length; ii++)
        {

            let key = info[ii];
            if (key !== oldname)
            {
                let skey = key + "~"; //make temporary key
                element[skey] = element[key]; //copy values to temp key
                delete element[key]; //delete old key
                element[key] = element[skey]; //copy key back to orginal name, preserving its position.
                delete element[skey]; //delete temp key
            }
            else
            {
                element[newname] = element[key];
                delete element[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```