# Trying to create a dynamic String name which changes

Tags: c#, variables, rest-client

I am trying to make a addjsonbody which expects a string at start but the string name changes due to poor architecture, i have been trying get set the string infront this value get picked up on script start i can store it in as a value but i need it as the string name.

```
createasset newAsset = new createasset();
                newAsset.organization = org;
                newAsset.location = loc;
                newAsset.name = newName;
                newAsset.customname1 = "value1";
                newAsset.customname2 = "value2";
                newAsset.customname3 = "value3";

request.AddJsonBody(newAsset);
```

i want to be able to change the name of customname1.

Comment: what is the question? are you looking for a library? a way to do it? when is it supposed to change? in runtime?  between builds?
Please improve your question.

Comment: I want to be able to change the string name like i change the value of the string or a way to create a string then be able to put a value inside the string during runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Newtonsoft JSON dynamic property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917164/newtonsoft-json-dynamic-property-name)