# Dynamic build the property name of a class.. is this possible

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on .net console application, and i have this class which I will Deserialzie a returned json on it:-

```
public class UdfFields
{
    public object udf_pick_34206 { get; set; }
    public string udf_pick_34205 { get; set; }
    public object udf_pick_34202 { get; set; }
    public object udf_mline_35402 { get; set; }
    public object udf_pick_34503 { get; set; }
    public object udf_pick_34502 { get; set; }
    public object udf_pick_35103 { get; set; }
    public object udf_pick_35101 { get; set; }
    public object udf_pick_29744 { get; set; }
    public object udf_sline_35701 { get; set; }
    public string udf_pick_35401 { get; set; }
    public object udf_pick_29753 { get; set; }
}
```

but the issue i am facing is that on some environments I will have different names for the `public object udf_pick_29744 { get; set; }` property .. for example it can be as follow:-

```
public object udf_pick_28744 { get; set; }
OR
public object udf_pick_26744 { get; set; }
```

so to make my code dynamic I define the following inside the `appsetting.json` file:-

```
"Field": "udf_pick_28744",
```

so can i get the value of the Field from my appsettins.json and dynamically name the property inside the class? and if this is not possible then how i can fix this issue?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I tired to use `JsonProperty` as follow,

```
public class UdfFields
    {
        static IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .AddJsonFile("appsetting.json", optional: false).Build();

        string name = config.GetSection("ServiceDesk").GetSection("field").Value;
        public object udf_pick_34206 { get; set; }
        public string udf_pick_34205 { get; set; }
        public object udf_pick_34202 { get; set; }
        public object udf_mline_35402 { get; set; }
        public object udf_pick_34503 { get; set; }
        public object udf_pick_34502 { get; set; }
        public object udf_pick_35103 { get; set; }
        public object udf_pick_35101 { get; set; }
        public object udf_pick_29744 { get; set; }
        public object udf_sline_35701 { get; set; }
        public string udf_pick_35401 { get; set; }
        public object udf_pick_29753 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = name)]
        public object riskdesc { get; set; }
    }
```

but i got this error:-

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
> property 'UdfFields.name'

Comment: Check out [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-5.0).

Comment: If you use Json.NET - you can use `DefaultContractResolver` check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33290710/5446495

Comment: @itsme86 can you advice more on this? how i can use it in my case?

Comment: Why don't you use ```JsonPropertyAttribute``` to assign a custom json name to the property instead of renaming the property itself. The parameter of the attribute can be changed at runtime.

Comment: Why aren't you exposing these as interfaces? You can deserialize that same object type and just have it implement different interfaces with the different names.

Comment: @RexHenderson can you check my edit please?

Comment: @Morse it did not work for me can you check my edit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Newtonsoft JSON dynamic property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917164/newtonsoft-json-dynamic-property-name)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko thanks but can you help in getting this working for me.. i am not sure how i need to modify the code?

Comment: I said it can be changed in runtime, not that it can be assigned in such a way. There are examples on SO on how to change the parameter of the attribute in runtime. One of the links was already provided by Andrei here.

Comment: @johnGu pls, see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (as I know) to change the name of the property at runtime. However it's possible to change the name of the property used in serialization logic.

One of the solutions is to mark the `UdfFields` class as **abstract**, mark the property `udf_pick_29744` (let's call it just `udf_pick_dynamic`) as abstract and define the children classes which implement the property `udf_pick_dynamic` with different `[JsonProperty(PropertyName)]` attribute values. It would be something like this:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsetting.json", optional: false).Build();
        var dynamicFieldName = config.GetSection("ServiceDesk").GetSection("field").Value;

        // Get json to be deserialized
        var json = GetJson(); 

        var udfFields = DeserializeJsonWithDynamicFieldName(json, dynamicFieldName);

        // Now you can get either 'udf_pick_29744' or 28744 or 26744 by accessing 'udfFields.udf_pick_dynamic' property
    }

    private static string GetJson()
    {
        // Here is your logic how to get json string
    }

    private static UdfFields DeserializeJsonWithDynamicFieldName(string json, string dynamicFieldName)
    {
        return dynamicFieldName switch
        {
            UdfPickDynamicFieldNames.Pick29744 => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UdfFields29744>(json),
            UdfPickDynamicFieldNames.Pick28744 => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UdfFields28744>(json),
            UdfPickDynamicFieldNames.Pick26744 => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UdfFields26744>(json),
            _ => throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported dynamic field name")
        };
    }
}

internal static class UdfPickDynamicFieldNames
{
    internal const string Pick29744 = "udf_pick_29744";
    internal const string Pick28744 = "udf_pick_28744";
    internal const string Pick26744 = "udf_pick_26744";
}

public abstract class UdfFields
{
    public object udf_pick_34206 { get; set; }
    public string udf_pick_34205 { get; set; }
    public object udf_pick_34202 { get; set; }
    public object udf_mline_35402 { get; set; }
    public object udf_pick_34503 { get; set; }
    public object udf_pick_34502 { get; set; }
    public object udf_pick_35103 { get; set; }
    public object udf_pick_35101 { get; set; }
    
    public abstract object udf_pick_dynamic { get; set; }
    public object udf_sline_35701 { get; set; }
    public string udf_pick_35401 { get; set; }
    public object udf_pick_29753 { get; set; }
}

public sealed class UdfFields29744 : UdfFields
{
    [JsonPropertyName(UdfPickDynamicFieldNames.Pick29744)]
    public override object udf_pick_dynamic { get; set; }
}

public sealed class UdfFields28744 : UdfFields
{
    [JsonPropertyName(UdfPickDynamicFieldNames.Pick28744)]
    public override object udf_pick_dynamic { get; set; }
}

public sealed class UdfFields26744 : UdfFields
{
    [JsonPropertyName(UdfPickDynamicFieldNames.Pick26744)]
    public override object udf_pick_dynamic { get; set; }
}
```