# JsonConverterAttribute is not working for Deserialization in ASP.NET Core 3.1 / 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I want set property names at runtime. I already achieve this for **serialization**.

For example. I have a simple model like as below:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DataModelConverter))]
public class DataModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a simple `DataModelConverter`, that inherited from `JsonConverter`:

```
public class DataModelConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();

        JObject jo = new JObject();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())
        {
            jo.Add(prop.Name == "Name" ? "FullName" : prop.Name, new JValue(prop.GetValue(value)));
        }

        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DataModel);
    }
}
```

And I have a simple controller like as below:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class NewtonController : ControllerBase
{
    public IEnumerable<DataModel> GetNewtonDatas([FromBody] DataModel input)
    {
        return new List<DataModel>()
        {
            new DataModel
            {
                Name="Ramil",
                Age=25
            },
            new DataModel
            {
                Name="Yusif",
                Age=26
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If I call this API, result will like as below (**Showing FullName Instead of Name**):

```
[
   {
       "FullName": "Ramil",
       "Age": 25
   },
   {
       "FullName": "Yusif",
       "Age": 26
   }
]
```

But I have a problem. This is not working for **deserialization**.

For example: If I call this API with  this body, then `Name` will **null**.

```
{
   "FullName":"Ramil"
}
```

My attribute is not working for **deserialization**. I want set property name via **attribute** for deserialization at runtime .

**I don't want use some middleware, I want to achieve this only by using the any attribute at runtime.  I must read JSON property names from my appsettings.json file.**

Thanks for help!

Comment: Well you have overridden [`CanRead`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanRead.htm) to return `false` so your converter will never be called during deserialization.  And since `"FullName"` does not have the same (case-invariant) name as the `Name` property, the `Name` property, it never gets set.  But why are you returning `false` from `CanRead`?  And why not just apply `[JsonProperty("FullName")]` to `Name`?

Comment: @dbc I must read json property names from my appsettings.json file. Therefore I need set the them at runtime. Thanks for reply, I check CanRead.

Comment: By *I don't want use some middleware, I want to achieve this only by using the any attribute at runtime.* do you mean that you don't want to use a custom contract resolver? If you use a custom contract resolver you can rename properties dynamically, see e.g. [Use different name for serializing and deserializing with Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44632448/3744182) or e.g. [Newtonsoft JSON dynamic property name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37917164/3744182).

Comment: @dbc thanks, I change CanRead to true, and ReadJson calling now. please mark it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overridden [`CanRead`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanRead.htm) to return `false`:

```
public override bool CanRead
{
    get { return false; }
}
```

This causes Json.NET not to call your your converter's `DataModelConverter.ReadJson()` method during deserialization, and instead use default deserialization.  Since `"FullName"` does not have the same (case-invariant) name as the `Name` property, it never gets set, and remains `null`.

To fix this, **remove** the override for `CanRead` (the default implementation returns `true`) and implement `ReadJson()`, e.g. as follows:

```
public class DataModelConverter : NameRemappingConverterBase
{
    static string AlternateName => "FullName";
    static string OriginalName => "Name";

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(DataModel);
    
    // Replace the below logic with name mappings from appsettings.json

    protected override string ToJsonPropertyName(JsonProperty property) => 
        string.Equals(property.UnderlyingName, OriginalName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? AlternateName : base.ToJsonPropertyName(property);
    
    protected override string FromJsonPropertyName(string name) => 
        string.Equals(name, AlternateName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? OriginalName : base.FromJsonPropertyName(name);
}

public abstract class NameRemappingConverterBase : JsonConverter
{
    protected virtual string ToJsonPropertyName(JsonProperty property) => property.PropertyName;
    
    protected virtual string FromJsonPropertyName(string name) => name;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartObject)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0}", reader.TokenType));
        var contract = (JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType);
        var value = existingValue ?? contract.DefaultCreator();
        while (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.PropertyName)
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0}", reader.TokenType));
            var name = FromJsonPropertyName((string)reader.Value);
            reader.ReadToContentAndAssert();
            var property = contract.Properties.GetProperty(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            if (!ShouldDeserialize(property))
            {
                reader.Skip();
            }
            else
            {
                var propertyValue = serializer.Deserialize(reader, property.PropertyType);
                property.ValueProvider.SetValue(value, propertyValue);
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var contract = (JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(value.GetType());
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var property in contract.Properties.Where(p => ShouldSerialize(p, value)))
        {
            var propertyValue = property.ValueProvider.GetValue(value);
            if (propertyValue == null && serializer.NullValueHandling == NullValueHandling.Ignore)
                continue;
            var name = ToJsonPropertyName(property);
            writer.WritePropertyName(name);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, propertyValue);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    protected virtual bool ShouldDeserialize(JsonProperty property) =>
        property != null && property.Writable;

    protected virtual bool ShouldSerialize(JsonProperty property, object value) =>
        property.Readable && !property.Ignored && (property.ShouldSerialize == null || property.ShouldSerialize(value));
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader ReadToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader) =>
        reader.ReadAndAssert().MoveToContentAndAssert();

    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WQxQ1X).

Comment: @RamilAliyev - glad to hear it!  I cleaned the answer up a bit by extracting `NameRemappingConverterBase`.