# Custom serialization with Newtonsoft JSON

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

Here's my issue : I have an object that will be serialized and send to SendGrid.

```cs
public class CustomFields
{
    [JsonProperty("e1_T")]
    public string? AdherentType { get; set; }     
}
```

As you can see, I need the property name to be "e1_T" in the Json. This way works fine but I need now to externalize the name of the JsonProperty to put it in a conf file that change betwen environement. I tried things like

```cs
public class CustomFields
{
    public string fieldName = "wololo";
    
    [JsonProperty(fieldName)]
    public string? AdherentType { get; set; }     
}
```

But it won't do the trick.

Any Idea how to make this append ?

Comment: I think the principles of what you're looking for can be found in this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917164/newtonsoft-json-dynamic-property-name

Comment: Consider changing your data structure - dictionary of String to String (instead of class with String fields) would be more suitable for this job

Comment: There is a section about custom serializer/converter on newtonsof samples and I would write one of those.  That way you can get the name and put it where you need it like config file.