# How can i replace or update the key with child value in json using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Actual Code:

```
{
    "workbookInformation": {
        "version": "9.1",
        "source-platform": "win"
    },
    "datasources": {
        "filename": "data",
        "caption": "Title",
        "version": "qqq.1",
        "cleaning": "no",
        "inline": "true",
        "validate": "no",
        "class": "excel-direct",
        "interpretationMode": "0"
    }
}
```

Output I need :

```
{
    "workbookInformation": {
        "version": "9.1",
        "source-platform": "win"
    },
    "Title": {
        "filename": "data",
        "caption": "Title",
        "version": "qqq.1",
        "cleaning": "no",
        "inline": "true",
        "validate": "no",
        "class": "excel-direct",
        "interpretationMode": "0"
    }
}
```

`caption` key value ie. `Title` needs to be replaced with `datasources`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391579/how-to-rename-json-key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new property directly on an object with [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and pass descriptor for the property being defined to this method with the result of [Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor):

```js
var obj = {"workbookInformation": {"version": "9.1","source-platform": "win"},"datasources": {"filename": "data","caption": "Title","version": "qqq.1","cleaning": "no","inline": "true","validate": "no","class": "excel-direct","interpretationMode": "0"}};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'Title', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'datasources'));
delete obj.datasources;

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your example, you can simply add a new item on the root JSON with the key "Title" and then remove the one with the key "datasources".

Assuming `json_obj` as your json object:

```
json_obj[json_obj.datasources.caption] = json_obj.datasources;
delete(json_obj.datasources);
```

Answer (score -1):

Parse the JSON string into a Javascript object so that you can modify it with ease.

`jsObj = JSON.parse(jsonData);`

Below I'm creating a new object with the desired keys and finally serialize it again.

```
jsonData = JSON.stringify({
  workbookInformation: jsObj.workbookInformation,
  Title: jsObj.datasources,
});
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)