# How can I update json data if it meets certain conditions?

Tags: php, arrays, json

My json data is like this :

```
$json_data = '{"2": "1", "3": "3"}';
```

Note :

> 2 = star,
>   1 = user,
>   3 = star, 
>   3 = user

If I have variables like this :

```
$user = 3;
$star = 4;
```

I want check variable `$user` exist in `$json_data` or not

If exist, it will update to be :

```
$json_data = '{"2": "1", "4": "3"}';
```

So, if `$user` exist in `$json_data`, it will update `$star`

I try like this :

```
<?php
    $user = 3;
    $star = 4;
    $json_data = '{"2": "1", "3": "3"}';
    $array_data = json_decode($json_data, true);
    if(in_array($user, $array_data))
    {
        // update here
    }
?>
```

I'm still confused, how to update it

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: You wanto to update `$star`? You just, `$start = {new_value}` asign a new value to it?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391579/how-to-rename-json-key

Comment: You might want to start by learning about data structures. Using surrogate keys like this in json is messy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to check if the `$user` exists, and in case it does, it will return the array index.

```
$key = array_search($user, $array_data); // Returns 3 i.e array key where $user exists

if ($key !== false) {
    $array_data[$star] = $array_data[$key]; // If key found, set value to $array_data[4]
    unset($array_data[$key]); // Remove the previous data $array_data[3]
}

echo json_encode($array_data);
```

Output:

```
{"2":"1","4":"3"}
```

Answer (score 0):

### I think this code help you to resolve your Query

> PHP Code

```
<?php
$result = array();
$json_data = '{"2": "1", "3": "3"}';
$user = 3;
$star = 4;
$dataArray = json_decode($json_data, true);
foreach($dataArray as $key=>$val) {
    if($val == $user) {
        $result[$star] = $val ;
    } else {
        $result[$key] = $val ;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r (json_encode($result));
?>
```