# Map the fourth element(dynamic name) of a json to a new name

Tags: json, ecmascript-6, lodash

My Json is as below. I have four fields in my json.

```
[
 {
    "id": "name1",
    "c1": "10",
    "c2": "20",
    "c3": "30"
        },
    {
    "id": "name2",
    "c1": "20",
    "c2": "40",
    "c3": "25"
        }
]
```

My desired result is as below.

```
[
 {
    "id": "name1",
    "c1": "10",
    "c2": "20"
     "a1": "50"

        },
    {
    "id": "name2",
    "c1": "20",
    "c2": "40",
     "a1": "50"
        }
]
```

I want to map my 4th element with a new name.

Comment: not a lodash-based solution, but similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391579/how-to-rename-json-key

Comment: convert the JSON object to json String and then replace the name c3 with a1.

Comment: Here the fields are dynamic. The fourth field can have any name (not just c3). I need to rename it. .

Comment: One way could be taking the first object in your array if it exists, use Object.keys(obj)[3] to get the correct fourth field name, and then do as the other solution suggests.  As an aside, I'd suggest editing the question to specify this dynamic field requirement is part of your problem

Comment: @GrumbleSnatch This idea helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```js
var jsonObj = [
 {
    "id": "name1",
    "c1": "10",
    "c2": "20",
    "c3": "30"
        },
    {
    "id": "name2",
    "c1": "20",
    "c2": "40",
    "c3": "25"
        }
];

for (var i in jsonObj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(jsonObj[i])[3];
  delete jsonObj[i][keys];
  jsonObj[i]["a1"] = "50";
}

console.log(jsonObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) to iterate and modify each item of the collection. We use [`lodash#toPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#toPairs) to convert the object into an array of key-values, update the value using [`lodash#update`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#update) from the 4th value which is the 3rd index of the collection into `['a1', '50']`. Lastly, use [`lodash#fromPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#fromPairs) to convert it back into an object.

```
var result = _.map(source, function(value) {
  return _(value)
    .toPairs()
    .update('3', _.constant(['a1', '50']))
    .fromPairs()
    .value();
});
```

```js
var source = [{
    "id": "name1",
    "c1": "10",
    "c2": "20",
    "c3": "30"
  },
  {
    "id": "name2",
    "c1": "20",
    "c2": "40",
    "c3": "25"
  }
];

var result = _.map(source, function(value) {
  return _(value)
    .toPairs()
    .update('3', _.constant(['a1', '50']))
    .fromPairs()
    .value();
});
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```