# Copy data from javascript object and assign them new keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, javascript-objects

I am getting data like this

```
    4706:"APN"
    4743:"Owner Name"
    4754:"Situs Address"
    6231 :"Mailing Address"
```

in a javascript object. When I copy this into new object it give same output while I want to replace it with my keys like this

```
    0:"APN"
    1:"Owner Name"
    2:"Situs Address"
    3 :"Mailing Address"
```

Is it possible to do that ? I am copying this object in tblheader

```
        tblHeader=features[i].attributes.fields.values;
```

Comment: Try this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391579/how-to-rename-json-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`Object.values()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjQtYChiYPVAhUEFZQKHaMWDTcQFggtMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_objects%2FObject%2Fvalues&usg=AFQjCNE5UlL1cEh99fUgeunohGICKbz8Ew) method ,its create the array of values .And use `Array#forEach()` for iteate the  array and append with new object

```js
var arr = {
  4706: "APN",
  4743: "Owner Name",
  4754: "Situs Address",
  6231: "Mailing Address",
}
var res ={};
Object.values(arr).forEach(function(a,b){
     res[b]=a
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: It will keep same sequence ? Or will change it every time? As I will get data differently every time and need same sequence .

Comment: yes...is it same sequence . `0,1` are index of the values from object

Comment: last thing , can I get it in array of object form ? l

Comment: yes using `Object.values(obj)` .Its return the array with `values` of the object .i was added with reference link with answer

Answer (score 1):

[Try this](https://jsfiddle.net/21ee3Lon/1/)

```
oldObject = 
{ 
4706:"APN",
4743:"Owner Name",
4754:"Situs Address",
6231 :"Mailing Address" 
};

 newObject = {}
     Object.keys(oldObject).map(function(key, index) {
     newObject[index] = oldObject[key];
  });
console.log(newObject)
```