# Ways to get external data into own mongodb (different structures)?

Tags: xml, mongodb, data-structures, import

I'm having an external Export of XML data which I want to have in my mongoDB. Because the data in the export doesnt fit my needs when it comes to the structure, I'd like to kind of "map" it.

Exmaple of kind of the data structure I'm getting from the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ogr:FeatureCollection
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation=""
     xmlns:ogr="http://ogr.maptools.org/"
     xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:Box>
      <gml:coord><gml:X>X.XXX</gml:X><gml:Y>Y.YYY</gml:Y></gml:coord>
      <gml:coord><gml:X>X.XXX</gml:X><gml:Y>Y.YYY</gml:Y></gml:coord>
    </gml:Box>
  </gml:boundedBy>                                                                               
  <gml:featureMember>
    <ogr:POI_TypeXYZ fid="POI_XYZ">
      <ogr:geometryProperty><gml:Point srsName="XYZ"><gml:coordinates>SAMPLE_DATA</gml:coordinates></gml:Point></ogr:geometryProperty>
      <ogr:ID>SAMPLE_DATA</ogr:ID>
      <ogr:TITLE>SAMPLE_DATA</ogr:TITLE>
      <ogr:STREET>SAMPLE_DATA</ogr:STREET>
      <ogr:NUM>SAMPLE_DATA</ogr:NUM>
      <ogr:PHONE>SAMPLE_DATA</ogr:PHONE>
    </ogr:POI_TypeXYZ>
  </gml:featureMember>
  <gml:featureMember>
    <ogr:POI_TypeXYZ fid="POI_XYZ">
      <ogr:geometryProperty><gml:Point srsName="XYZ"><gml:coordinates>SAMPLE_DATA</gml:coordinates></gml:Point></ogr:geometryProperty>
      <ogr:ID>SAMPLE_DATA</ogr:ID>
      <ogr:TITLE>SAMPLE_DATA</ogr:TITLE>
      <ogr:STREET>SAMPLE_DATA</ogr:STREET>
      <ogr:NUM>SAMPLE_DATA</ogr:NUM>
      <ogr:PHONE>SAMPLE_DATA</ogr:PHONE>
    </ogr:POI_TypeXYZ>
  </gml:featureMember>
</ogr:FeatureCollection>
```

And for example I'd rather have different names for the fields etc. and have full control over that data.

Are there any tools that could help? Or what is the general strategy to handle such things?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a 3 step process:

1. Convert `xml` to `JSON`.
2. Change the name of the fields. refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13391613/7579549) to know how to change the key of JSON object.(You have full control over data here)
3. Convert `JSON` object to `BSON` and store it into Mongodb.

> import json
>
> data = json.loads(document)
>
> mongocollection.insert(data)

Comment: I tried converting my JSON to BSON (just to test it with an online coverter) but how do I import a BSON file? mongoimport seems not to work.

Comment: what do you mean by import a BSON file? what are you trying to import?

Comment: Not that familiar with MongoDB yet, how am I supposed to store BSON (and how can I convert it from JSON) into my MongoDB?

Comment: You don't need to worry about changing JSON to Bson, MongoDriver will take care of it. Check my edit. If this solves your problem, please  mark it as correct answer

Comment: Gonna try asap. Thx. Question: Is "import json" == cli -> mongoimport? And what do you mean with data = json.loads(document)?

Comment: document is the JSON string. json.loads() will convert the json document into Python object

Comment: No, import json is to use json libraries. For mongo you need to install PyMongo. Follow this document. (https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/python/client/)

Comment: So is this still the same if I use nodejs to import? I'm not sure if I get what you say.

Comment: You need to add libraries to use JSON and Mongo. JavaScript has library for both. Please mark answer as correct if it helped you.

Comment: Yeah thats clear. When I asked, I just used JS to convert the XML data to a JSON file I needed an wrote it to disk (output.json). And then I tried to import that file via mongoimport.exe. I'd really like to accept your answer but to be honest it rather confused me a bit. Maybe we talked past each other.

Comment: Would it be helpful if I therefore update my question? Because currently I have the import ready but overwriting it currently is a problem.

Comment: So I asked a new question because the circumstances changed a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47697822/correctly-inserting-and-or-updating-many-datasets-to-mongodb-using-mongoose