# Rename JSON key in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

hello friends i want to rename my JSON key so below i my code

```js
 var json = '[{"Status":"Success","Data":[{"UserID":null,"UserName":null,"EmailID":null,"EmailIDExists":false,"Active":null,"Country":null,"WishListID":"31","WishListName":"General","WishListItems":[{"WishListItemID":"3","ItemCode":"4414082000005","ItemName":"Notebook 4414-082","Image":"http://aljeel.gct.om/ProductsImages/4414082000005_MT1.jpg","ItemPrice":0.500,"CreatedDate":"25/05/2018"}]},{"UserID":null,"UserName":null,"EmailID":null,"EmailIDExists":false,"Active":null,"Country":null,"WishListID":"24","WishListName":"Default","WishListItems":[]}],"Message":null}]';

var obj = JSON.parse(json)[0].Data;
obj.data = obj.WishListItems;
delete obj.WishListItems;

json = JSON.stringify([obj]);
console.log("FINAL JSON " + (json));
```

i want to change **WatchListItem** key with **data** key but when i run above code JSON key is not replacing any idea how can i solve this?

Comment: Data key is also an array so you may need to do `var obj = JSON.parse(json)[0].Data[0];` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rename JSON key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391579/how-to-rename-json-key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this :**

```js
var json = '[{"Status":"Success","Data":[{"UserID":null,"UserName":null,"EmailID":null,"EmailIDExists":false,"Active":null,"Country":null,"WishListID":"31","WishListName":"General","WishListItems":[{"WishListItemID":"3","ItemCode":"4414082000005","ItemName":"Notebook 4414-082","Image":"http://aljeel.gct.om/ProductsImages/4414082000005_MT1.jpg","ItemPrice":0.500,"CreatedDate":"25/05/2018"}]},{"UserID":null,"UserName":null,"EmailID":null,"EmailIDExists":false,"Active":null,"Country":null,"WishListID":"24","WishListName":"Default","WishListItems":[]}],"Message":null}]';

var obj = JSON.parse(json)[0].Data;

console.log("Before replace", obj);

var res = obj.map(item => {
  item.data = item.WishListItems;
  delete item.WishListItems;
  return item;
});

console.log("After replace", res);
```

Answer (score 1):

`obj` was `undefined`. Changing `obj` to `obj[0]` fixed it.

```js
var json = '[{"Status":"Success","Data":[{"UserID":null,"UserName":null,"EmailID":null,"EmailIDExists":false,"Active":null,"Country":null,"WishListID":"31","WishListName":"General","WishListItems":[{"WishListItemID":"3","ItemCode":"4414082000005","ItemName":"Notebook 4414-082","Image":"http://aljeel.gct.om/ProductsImages/4414082000005_MT1.jpg","ItemPrice":0.500,"CreatedDate":"25/05/2018"}]},{"UserID":null,"UserName":null,"EmailID":null,"EmailIDExists":false,"Active":null,"Country":null,"WishListID":"24","WishListName":"Default","WishListItems":[]}],"Message":null}]';

var obj = JSON.parse(json)[0].Data[0];

obj.data = obj.WishListItems;
delete obj.WishListItems;

json = JSON.stringify([obj]);
console.log("FINAL JSON " + (json));
```

Comment: with your code it remove inside WishListitem data , it is not replace WishListItems with data key

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya firstly he creates a new node with the name 'data' where he assignes the value from the 'WishListItems' node and then he deletes the second node, so you will have a key named data with the 'WishListItems' content. Did you try it?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. I have no idea what you are trying to archieve.

Comment: @Red My question is clear i want to rename WishListItems key with data key, i already highlight those key in my question

Comment: Babis.amas: i tried above code but it is remove inside WishListItems array data i want to just rename WishListItems with data key

Comment: @Red you have to assign that list to `obj[0].data`

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that your obj is not one object it is an array. you have to use

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json)[0].Data[0];
```

in the assignement.
Or to do it for **all objects**

use forEach like below

```
    var json = '[{"Status":"Success","Data":[{"UserID":null,"UserName":null,"EmailID":null,"EmailIDExists":false,"Active":null,"Country":null,"WishListID":"31","WishListName":"General","WishListItems":[{"WishListItemID":"3","ItemCode":"4414082000005","ItemName":"Notebook 4414-082","Image":"http://aljeel.gct.om/ProductsImages/4414082000005_MT1.jpg","ItemPrice":0.500,"CreatedDate":"25/05/2018"}]},{"UserID":null,"UserName":null,"EmailID":null,"EmailIDExists":false,"Active":null,"Country":null,"WishListID":"24","WishListName":"Default","WishListItems":[]}],"Message":null}]';

JSON.parse(json)[0].Data.forEach(obj=>{
obj.data = obj.WishListItems;
    delete obj.WishListItems;
 json = JSON.stringify([obj]);
    console.log("FINAL JSON " + (json));
});
```