# Change JSON key and don't lose any data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to change json key but I can not manage

I tried to write a function:

```
modifySlotKey(requestObjectIntent, slotValue) {

requestObjectIntent['slots']['toChange'] = requestObjectIntent['slots'][slotValue]

return requestObjectIntent;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

My json is like that:

```
"slots": {
  "toChange": {
    "name": "query",
    "value": "torte",
    "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
    "source": "USER"
  }
}
```

but I want to change it to:

```
"slots": {
  "slotValue": {
    "name": "query",
    "value": "torte",
    "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
    "source": "USER"
  }
}
```

Could somebody help me please to solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename JSON key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391579/how-to-rename-json-key)

Comment: When you say `JSON`, you implicitly says you have a `string`. So, you have a `string` or an `object` as input?

Comment: I have an Object and it is not the same case as  @TheMri suggest!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is fine but you only need to change the order of variables(slotValue = 'toChange') and delete de older key before return.

```
requestObjectIntent['slots'][slotValue] = requestObjectIntent['slots']['toChange];
delete(requestObjectIntent['slots']['toChange']);
```

I do a little example and works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/g7t4Lan5/1/