# How to use string varaible value as key name in object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

In Typescript I would like the `myObj` variable to be:

`{'key01': 'value01'}`

So I go ahead with:

```
let keyName = 'key01';
let myObj = {keyName: 'value01'};

console.log(myObj);
```

But the resulting variable is

```
{ keyName: 'value01' }
```

Can I use the value of the `keyName` variable to use as the key name for the variable `myObj`?

Comment: I think you need this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391579/how-to-rename-json-key

Comment: Please post it as an answer so we could up vote it

Comment: this can not be posted as answer. if this was helpful you can mark it as helpful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) property accessor:

```js
let keyName = 'key01';
let myObj = {};
myObj[keyName] = 'value01';

console.log(myObj);
```

For TypeScript, use:

```js
let keyName = 'key01';
let myObj:any = {};
myObj[keyName] = 'value01';
```

Comment: Is it designed to run in Javascript or Typescript? Typescript raises an error

Comment: ```Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

let keyName: string```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to waste space with an extra line of code for defining the main object and then defining the custom key, you can use bracket notation inline.

```js
let keyName = 'key01';
let myObj = { [keyName]: 'value01' };

console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the value of your object using the variable `keyName` you can use the following.

```js
let keyName = "newValue";
let myObject = {keyName: "oldValue"}
myObject.keyName = keyName

console.log(myObject)
```

Comment: OP wanted the resulting object to be { key01: "value01" }, based off of the dynamic naming of the value of `keyName`. This is just creating an object with a static key name of `keyName` and assigning it the value `"oldValue"`, then reassigning it to have the value `"newValue"`