# Convert a hash of objects to json in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I have a hash H which should contain various users as json. "users" list contains all users and every user object contains various user's details like name, age etc. I don't want to iterate over every user in the list and do `user.as_json` and then merge into the hash.

Is there a single line query which does this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183786/how-to-convert-a-ruby-hash-object-to-json

Comment: is this an action response?, with something maybe like a `@users` variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, in your action convert it to `JSON` by using `to_json`

```
@users = users.to_json
```

In the Javascript code, parse it using jQuery's `$.parseJSON()`

```
$.parseJSON(@users)
```