# Rails Generate JSON for API POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm following some API docs and as part of a post I need to generate some JSON in this format:

```
{
 "panelist": {
 "email_address": "test@example.com",
 "gender": "m",
 "postal_code": "12345",
 "year_of_birth": 1997,
 “variables”: [1000,1001]
 }
}
```

What's the best way to generate this in Rails (I don't have a `Panelist` model, rather most of these things are stored in my `Appuser` model, so `gender` will actually be `@appuser.gender`).

In the past I've just done something like

```
params = {
 "gender" => "m",
 "postal_code" => "12345"
}
```

and then in my request `set_form_data`:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data(params)

response = http.request(request)
```

But the nested params inside `panelist` are throwing me off.

I did try using the `to_json` to simply do this:

```
appuser = { "panelist" => { "email" => "test@example.com", "zip" => "12345" } }
appuser.to_json
 => "{\"panelist\":{\"email\":\"test@example.com\",\"zip\":\"12345\"}}"
```

But it seems like I'm more or less just hardcoding the json. Which I suppose I could do, but it feels like there could be an easier way.

Comment: How often are you going to send data in this format? If it is more than once, I would consider making a model for it.

Comment: Pretty often. I'll look into the new model. I was initially leaning away from that since the data already existed in the appuser model.

Comment: If this model is a subset of the AppUser model, then the AppUser could have a method which returns one of these. Then you just call AppUser.to_special_model.to_json

Comment: Ah, good thought! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a helper library, 'json', that adds a 'to_json' method to every object. Just add a require for this, and then call params.to_json.

[How to convert a ruby hash object to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183786/how-to-convert-a-ruby-hash-object-to-json)

Comment: I'm not sure I want to override it for this though - as I actually need the to_json method for interaction in my app via my Backbone front-end. This piece is solely for interaction with the outside service...

Comment: It only adds the method to objects that have not already defined it themselves. If you have a model which declares its own 'to_json', then that will still be used when you call it.

Comment: Played around a bit and added an edit using the `to_json`call