# How can I convert a hash into JavaScript format?

Tags: json, ruby

I have a hash

```
{:name =>"douglas_hettinger@braunlebsack.io"}
```

I am trying to convert this hash into the following JavaScript format.

```
{"name" : "douglas_hettinger@braunlebsack.io"}
```

I tried:

```
{:name=>"douglas_hettinger@braunlebsack.io"}.to_json
```

which gives the output:

```
"{\"name\":\"douglas_hettinger@braunlebsack.io\"}"
```

Parsing it with JSON gives:

```
JSON.parse({:name=>"douglas_hettinger@braunlebsack.io"}.to_json) 
# => {"name"=>"douglas_hettinger@braunlebsack.io"}
```

Comment: I think the top answer here is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183786/how-to-convert-a-ruby-hash-object-to-json

Comment: `"{\"name\":\"douglas_hettinger@braunlebsack.io\"}"` is the `inspect` of the string, the default way strings are presented in console. The string *content* (escaped by backslashes by `inspect`, which is why you may have thought the result to be wrong) is: `{"name":"douglas_hettinger@braunlebsack.io"}`, exactly what you want. use `puts {...}.to_json` instead of just `{...}.to_json` in console to verify this.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

`to_json` should work:

```
require 'json'
{:name =>"douglas_hettinger@braunlebsack.io"}.to_json
#=> "{"name":"douglas_hettinger@braunlebsack.io"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want to recreate the same hash that you converted  to JSON.

This could be done by passing option [symbolize_names: true](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) to JSON.parse method.

The code would look something like this

```
JSON.parse({:name=>"douglas_hettinger@braunlebsack.io"}.to_json, symbolize_names: true)
```