# How to properly create JSON with variables?

Tags: json, ruby

I have several variables, not literals, that I want include in a json string. This doesn't work:

```
a1 = get_email
a2 = get_user_name

json1 = '{"email": a1, "username": a2}'
```

because the variables aren't evaluated.

And doing this the other way around will make json invalid because single quotation marks aren't allowed in json:

```
a1 = get_email
a2 = get_user_name

json1 = "{'email': a1, 'username': a2}"
```

How can I create a json with those variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a ruby hash object to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183786/how-to-convert-a-ruby-hash-object-to-json)

Comment: You can create the hash with the a's values, `{email: a1, ...}`. Try that.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way to do this is to first use a hash:

```
a1 = get_email
a2 = get_user_name

json1 = {'email'=> a1, 'username'=> a2}.to_json
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `to_json` as in adrienbourgeois's answer is the correct way after all, but going along the lines of what you suggested, you should have done:

```
json1 = "{\"email\": #{a1}, \"username\": #{a2}}"
```

provided that `a1.to_s` and `a2.to_s` give the JSON format of whatever object you have in it (which you have not made clear in your question).

Comment: i don't understand your answer