# Is there a way to convert a Ruby hash to JSON in Node.JS outside of Rails?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ruby

I cannot find any built-in functions/modules in Node.JS to convert a Ruby hash into a JSON object.  I am very familiar with the method of using Ruby to do this, e.g. see [How to convert a ruby hash object to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183786/how-to-convert-a-ruby-hash-object-to-json/3184039#3184039).  I am hoping for something similar in Node.JS.  Of course, any workaround would also be fine.  E.g., is there a way to run embedded ruby in Node.JS?  From the searching I've done, it does not seem like there is anything "out-of-the-box" to do this.

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: A hash is an internal data structure in Ruby. Node.js runs Javascript, which is a different language and has its own internal data structures. So you wouldn't really have a "Ruby hash" inside Node.js. Do you mean a string representation of a Ruby hash? If you print a Ruby hash it outputs it in a particular format (using Ruby notation such as "=>"). Are you loading this string into Node.js? If so you can write a parser that loads that string representation of a Ruby hash into a Javascript object, and then convert that object to JSON

Comment: "is there a way to run embedded ruby in Node.JS" If you have Ruby installed on the system, you can run Ruby via system calls. E.g. you could make a mini script which takes a Ruby hash as input and outputs a JSON hash.