# New to Ruby - how do I shuffle a string?

Tags: ruby

Want to shuffle a string.
This is my code:
what is wrong about it?
Thanks.

```
>> def string_shuffle(s)
>>   s.split('').shuffle(s.length()).join
>>   return s
>> end
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If understand you correctly, you want this:

```
def string_shuffle(s)
  s.split("").shuffle.join
end

string_shuffle("The Ruby language")
=> "ea gu bgTayehRlnu"
```

Comment: If you need a lot of shuffling it makes sense to use `shuffle!` instead of `shuffle`. It is a bit faster.

Comment: You can use `chars` instead of `split("")`

Answer (score 8):

`return s` is both not needed and wrong. Not needed because Ruby returns whatever is executed last and wrong because you are not changing s, you are creating a new string.

Furthermore, you can just add the `shuffle` method directly to String if you find it useful, but beware of monkeypatching too much.

```
class String

  def shuffle
    self.split('').shuffle.join
  end
end
```

Comment: you could put this in a module then apply the module to the string you want to affect, that ways it wont affect other strings in the app and cause unwanted effects.

Comment: @Joseph, how do you get a module to affect a specific string instance? An example or link would be great. Also, Josh, you may find this [question about monkeypatching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394144/what-does-monkey-patching-exactly-mean-in-ruby) useful.

Comment: @Zabba http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html check extend. it monkey patches a variable rather than a class.

Comment: Besides, explore the differences between including a module and extending it. One common pattern is using the self.included method in the module for extending another one, so it _includes_ a few class methods.

Answer (score 7):

This is faster.
`'hello'.chars.shuffle.join`

Test yourself:

```
require 'benchmark'

str = 'Hello' * 100
Benchmark.bm(10) do |x|
  x.report('chars')       { str.chars.shuffle.join }
  x.report('split')       { str.split('').shuffle.join }
  x.report('split regex') { str.split(//).shuffle.join }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

shuffle does not accept (and need) arguments. Use:

```
 s.split(//).shuffle.to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
s.split('').shuffle.join
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
s.chars.shuffle.join
```

Example:

```
s = "Hello, World!"
puts s.chars.shuffle.join
```

Output:

```
olH!l rWdel,o
```