# Ruby - extend built-in variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, types, metaprogramming

I would like to extend the functionality of variables in Ruby. The reason is I am working on something similar of a type system or value checker (this sounds a bit crazy but the whole idea is to long to explain, just the reason I would like to extend default variables).

I have read that in Ruby, everything is an object; so variables are objects. And Ruby is supposed to be quite liberal concerning what can be changed via meta-programming.

Is there some kind of 'Class' associated with local variables that I could extend?

I would like to associate a string-variable for each variable that holds a string representation of a type. Further I would like to intercept variable assignments and execute a method each time a new value is assigned to a variable. This is so I can check, if the new value is correct according to the type (stored as string in the Variable).

If local variables in Ruby are defined as object of a class, I can extend that class or modify it via a ruby mixin.

The workaround would be to create a new class for my Variables (and not use the build in local variables of Ruby). This class can have a value attribute, a attribute (stored as string) for the type and a get- and set-method. This way I can solve my problem, but I would like to extend the built in variables in ruby, if that is possible.

**current work in progress**

```
class Fixnum
        attr_accessor :tp
        @tp

        def mytype ( type )
                @tp = type
        end
        def typecheck
                #call typechecker
                puts "checked"
        end
end
```

Test Code:

```
a = 3
a.mytype("nat")
puts a.tp
a.typecheck
```

There are still two problems.
*First*, I think it is not possible to add a new constructor to Fixnum. *Second*, I would like to intercept the variable access, i.e. "b = a" calls the method 'typecheck' of a. But this would require something similar to Aspect Oriented Programming and I am not sure if this can be solved with Ruby's meta-programming facilitates.

Comment: Variables aren't really objects. They're mere references to the Objects that were assigned to the them...

Comment: Reminds me of http://pastie.org/4608297

Answer (score 4):

> I have read that in Ruby, everything is an object

That depends on your definition of "*object*" and every-"*thing*". "*Object*" can mean "*entity that can be manipulated by the program*" (which I will call **object** from now on), or "*value that is a member of the object system*" (which I will call `Object` from now on).

In Ruby, everything that can be manipulated by the program (i.e. every **object**) is also an `Object`, i.e. an instance of a class. This is unlike Java, for example, where *primitives* can be manipulated by the program (i.e. are **objects** in that sense of the word), but aren't `Objects`. In Ruby, this distinction doesn't exist: every **object** is an `Object` and every `Object` is also an **object**.

However, there are *things* in the language, which *cannot* be manipulated by the program and which aren't instances of a class, i.e. they are neither **object** s nor `Object`s. These are, for example, methods, variables, syntax, parameter lists, arguments lists, keywords.

Note: you can use Ruby's reflection API to give you an object that *represents* a method or a parameter list, but that object is only a proxy, it is not the real thing.

So, when we say "*everything is an object*", what we really mean is that "every **object** is an `Object`", i.e. that everything which can be manipulated by the program is also a member of the object system, or in other words, there are no values outside of the object system (unlike primitives in Java). We do *not* mean that everything that exists in the language can also be manipulated at runtime by the program.

> so variables are objects

No, unfortunately, they are neither **object** s nor `Object`s.

This is also clearly stated in the Ruby Language Specification (emphasis added by me):

> ## 6.2 Variables
>
> ### 6.2.1 General description
>
> A variable is denoted by a name, and **refers to** an object, which is called the value of the variable.
>   **A variable itself is not an object**.

In the book [*The Ruby Programming Language* by Matz and David Flanagan](http://Amazon.Com/dp/0596516177/) it says on page 2:

> every value is an object

Note, it doesn't say every-*thing*, only every *value*.

See also the question [Is variable is object in ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/a/8385471/2988/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things you can do. For starters, all (or very nearly all) Ruby classes (including "primitives" such as numbers) support a to_s method which returns a string representation of the object. For numbers, to_s will just return the string representation of that number (e.g., "42" for 42). The string value returned for other classes will vary. The nice thing is that you can [override a class's methods via "monkey patching"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394144/what-does-monkey-patching-exactly-mean-in-ruby). Here's an extremely contrived example:

```
class Array
  def to_s
    return "An array of size #{self.size}."
  end
end

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
puts a.to_s
# => "An array of size 4."
```

For your other question regarding executing a method every time a variable's value is set, the way to handle this is to always interact with the variable through its accessor methods. This way you can implement custom code inside a property's getter and setter methods (or simply call another method from inside the accessor). Like this:

```
class MyClass
  # Use the default getter for var.
  attr_reader :var      

  def initialize
    @var = 1
  end

  # Custom setter for var.
  def var= v
    @var = v
    puts "var changed to #{v}"
  end
end

mc = MyClass.new
mc.var = 9
# => "var chaged to 9"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, but it only works for globals:

```
$type_checked = {:$a => String, :$b => Array}
$type_checked.keys.each do |var|
  trace_var(var) do |obj|
    puts "hey, don't assign #{var} to a #{obj.class}" unless $type_checked[var] == obj.class
    #or raise an Error
  end
end

$a = 1
$a = "a"
$b = 1

#output:
#hey, don't assign $a to a Fixnum
#hey, don't assign $b to a Fixnum
```

But this clearly goes against the grain of the language.