# Undefined method for string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't understand why I can't call the method `colorize` from color.rb.

I wrote `include color` inside the class, but when I try to execute the script I get this error in `wget`:

```
undefined method `colorize' for #<String:0x00000001152d30>
```

This is the code:

```
$LOAD_PATH << './lib'
 require 'color'

class Download
 include color
 def wget(arr)
   FileUtils.cd('/mnt/list')
   site = "xxxxx"
    arr.each do |f|
      wget = system("wget #{site}#{f}")
      logger.info("wget: #{f}".colorize("blue"))
    end
 end
end
```

The file color.rb with the method `colorize`

```
module Color

 def colorize(color, options = {})
   background = options[:background] || options[:bg] || false
   style = options[:style]
   offsets = ["gray","red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "magenta", "cyan","white"]
   styles =   ["normal","bold","dark","italic","underline","xx","xx","underline","xx","strikethrough"]
   start = background ? 40 : 30
   color_code = start + (offsets.index(color) || 8)
   style_code = styles.index(style) || 0
   "\e[#{style_code};#{color_code}m#{self}\e[0m"
 end
end
```

Comment: You're including `Color` in *your* class, not `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you want to call `colorize` method on `String`s instance, you should [monkeypatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394144/what-does-monkey-patching-exactly-mean-in-ruby) the `String` class:

```
class String
  include Color
end
```

`include color` string in your `Download` class is senseless.

The snippet might be put anywhere in your code, e. g. right after the `Color` module definition. Since you have `String` class monkeypatched as shown above, you yield an ability to call `colorize` on string instances. The summing up:

```
module Color
 def colorize(color, options = {})
 ....
 end
end

class String
  include Color
end

puts 'a'.colorize(...) # ⇒ works
```

Comment: why i need to add a class string in the file ?

Comment: thanks it's work but i dont understand for class string

Comment: Did you follow the link I provided?