# Monkey patch method on single object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monkeypatching

I would like to override the behavior of the `update_attributes` method on a **single** instance of a model class.  Assuming the variable is called `@alert` what is the best way to go about this? To be clear, I **do not** want to modify the behavior of this method for the entire class.

---

**DISCLAIMER:**

I need to do this to force the method to return `false` when I want it to so that I can write unit tests for the error handling code following. I understand it may not be the best practice.

Comment: I was about to correct your use of the term "monkey patch"--thinking it applied only to modifications of Ruby's built-in methods--but after googling it appears there is no consensus as to its meaning.  See, for example, [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394144/what-does-monkey-patching-exactly-mean-in-ruby).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Historically "money patch" refers to stomping existing methods with your own implementations where these take over completely. In this case it's more of a "mock" operation, where it's only altering a single object, and other objects, both existing and those created in the future, are unaffected.

Comment: This smells a lot like a method stub, which any decent test framework will accommodate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just define a method on the object:

```
class Thing
  def greeting
    'yo, man'
  end
end

Thing.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:greeting]

object = Thing.new
  #=> #<Thing:0x007fc4ba276c90> 

object.greeting
  #=> "yo, man"
```

Define two methods on `object` (which will be instance methods in `object`'s singleton class.

```
def object.greeting
  'hey, dude'
end

def object.farewell
  'see ya'
end

object.methods(false)
  #=> [:greeting, :farewell] 
object.singleton_class.instance_methods(false) #=> [:greeting, :farewell]

object.greeting
  #=> "hey, dude" 
object.farewell
  #=> "see ya"

new_obj = Thing.new
new_obj.greeting
  #=> "yo, man"
new_obj.farewell
  #NoMethodError: undefined method `farewell' for #<Thing:0x007fe5a406f590>
```

Remove `object`'s singleton method `greeting`.

```
object.singleton_class.send(:remove_method, :greeting)

object.methods(false)
  #=> [:farewell] 
object.greeting
  #=> "yo, man"
```

Another way to remove `:greeting` from the `object`'s singleton class is as follows.

```
class << object
  remove_method(:greeting)
end
```

Comment: Sometimes this is more cleanly done by making a module and mixing that in to the individual object.

Comment: Typo: `Thing.new hi` should be `Thing.new.hi`.

The exception will then be `NoMethodError: undefined method \`hi' for #<Thing:0x000000.......>` instead of `NameError: ...`

Answer (score 1):

After creating an object, call "define_method" on it:

```
object = Thing.new
object.define_method("update_attributes") { return false }
```

That done, `object.update_attributes` should now return `false`

Comment: The object inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` and I am getting a `NoMethodError` attempting to call `define_method` on it. Any idea? It may be obvious but I am relatively new to the Ruby on Rails subtleties.

Comment: `define_method` is only defined on `Module`, but `object` is not a `Module`, it's a `Thing`.