# Rails Custom Scrubber which *modifies* PermitScrubber default behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-sanitizing

If one uses Rails::Html::PermitScrubber and doesn't specify a value for tags or attributes it defaults to using reasonable defaults from Loofah::HTML5::Scrub.  However, as soon as you set tags or attributes it chooses a completely different code path that ignores those defaults.

I want to start with the default functionality provided by Rails::Html::PermitScrubber (i.e. when tags/attributes aren't specified) and just make a few small changes but looking at the class implementation it seems like I would need to basically copy and reimplement half the PermitScrubber methods just to access that default functionality. And the defaults provided by Loofah::HTML5::Scrub don't seem to be part of any existing Loofah::Scrubber class.

So how do I make *minor* changes to the default operation of Rails::Html::PermitScrubber without reimplementing half the class?  Surely this is a very common use case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can just subclass `Rails::Html::PermitScrubber` and override `keep_node?` to get needed behavior (not changing code path if tags are present).

The code of original `keep_node?` is

```
  def keep_node?(node)
    if @tags
      allowed_node?(node)
    else
      Loofah::HTML5::Scrub.allowed_element?(node.name)
    end
  end
```

Probably, that is the part that you want to update.

Or, you can [monkey-patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394144/what-does-monkey-patching-exactly-mean-in-ruby) the existing class if subclass does not suit your case.

Comment: This is mostly what I ended up doing but for anyone else who comes across this you are also going to need to override scrub_attributes as well (and maybe scrub_attribute? if you still use this in the overridden scrub_attributes).  I was just hoping that there was some easier way to do this but it turned out this wasn't so bad.